# 2007 hyundai Tucson 2.0l petrol wiring harness connectors

Tags: hyundai, connector, tucson

I have a 2007 Hyundai Tucson, 2.0 l petrol, when I reconnected the intake wiring harness, i have a 2 pin connector that is not connected/unmatched....Oil/cam sensor, water temp sensor, airflow sensor, coil pack sensor are all connected... what have I missed...?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! A picture here would tell a 1000 words. Please consider updating your question with an image of the defiant connector and we *might* be able to help you. Also, have you tried just turning the car on? Sometimes if a sensor is not connected it will pop an OBDII code, which will tell you *exactly* what you've left behind. I had a 2004 Escape which wouldn't start. Figured out it was the crank sensor I'd forgotten to plug in by just this way.

Comment: Did you make a record of exactly which ones you disconnected when starting? Some cars have connectors that are only used for some parts and my car has a connector that is used by the dealer until the vehicle is sold and then it becomes spare...